# How can I generate \x-escaped UTF-8 in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, python-unicode

I want to convert a unicode input to a \x escaped, 7-bit-ascii-clean reprentation of a UTF-8 byte sequence.

This is analogous to what I need, but instead of `"\u222a"` I would like to generate `"\xe2\x88\xaa"`

```
>>> codecs.encode(u"\u222A", 'ascii', 'backslashreplace')
'\\u222a'
```

This looks like it is generating the desired result:

```
>>> u"\u222A".encode('utf-8')
'\xe2\x88\xaa'
```

But that is merely an escaped representation. The actual result isn't 12 ascii bytes, it's 3 UTF-8 bytes:

```
>>> [ord(c) for c in u"\u222A".encode('utf-8')]
[226, 136, 170]
```

I could abuse that escaped representation to get what I want, stripping off the leading and trailing quote that repr adds:

```
>>> repr(u"\u222A".encode('utf-8'))[1:-1]
'\\xe2\\x88\\xaa'
>>> [ord(c) for c in repr(u"\u222A".encode('utf-8'))[1:-1]]
[92, 120, 101, 50, 92, 120, 56, 56, 92, 120, 97, 97]
```

Yuck. This is a little better:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> ''.join('\\x' + binascii.hexlify(c) for c in u"\u222A".encode('utf-8'))
'\\xe2\\x88\\xaa'
>>> [ord(c) for c in ''.join('\\x' + binascii.hexlify(c) for c in u"\u222A".encode('utf-8'))]
[92, 120, 101, 50, 92, 120, 56, 56, 92, 120, 97, 97]
```

Is a better way to do this?

Comment: why would you do that? .... I dont understand why you would ever want to do this ... in terms of how ... whats wrong with repr? that seems to do what you want .... although I still dont understand why in the world you would ever want to do this

Comment: Do you mind if I ask why you need the backslash form? Maybe there's an easier way. For example, you can create a JSON representation with `json.dumps(obj)`

Comment: The `repr` line does exactly what you want, giving you 12 ASCII bytes in the range of 32-127. Why the "Yuck"?

Comment: @NedBatchelder and JoranBeasley: sanitizing untrusted input for use in file paths and similar situations. Come to think of it, I could probably leverage urllib for my purposes.

Comment: @MarkRansom I generally assume `repr`'s format is subject to change and not part of the class's public API.

Comment: OK, valid concern, I think `repr` actually does change in Python 3. What's the problem with the last solution you present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> u'\u222A'.encode('utf-8').encode('string-escape')
'\\xe2\\x88\\xaa'
>>> print u'\u222A'.encode('utf-8').encode('string-escape')
\xe2\x88\xaa
```

Comment: `'string-escape'` isn't compatible with Python 3. Other than that this is a really simple way to go.

Comment: `3>> '\u222A'.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1').encode('unicode-escape')`
`b'\\xe2\\x88\\xaa'`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll find a solution that isn't ugly. Here's one that retains any ASCII characters that are in the original string without converting them to a hex sequence.

```
''.join(c if 32 <= ord(c) <= 127 else '\\x{:02x}'.format(ord(c)) for c in u"\u222A".encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: What about literal backslashes?